# Java Generics: custom compatible empty/non-empty lists

Tags: java, generics

I have this task to make a custom generic list implementation that adheres to the following requirements:

- has 3 classes:1 abstract class (let's say `ExampleAbstractList`), one empty list implementation (e.g. `ExampleEmptyList`) and one non-empty list (e.g. `ExampleNonEmptyList`)
- it has to be possible to add/concat the two non-abstract classes together from both ways (e.g. add an non-empty list to the empty list and viceversa)
- the "developers" should work with the abstract class (e.g. `ExampleAbstractList<Integer> list2   = new ExampleNonEmptyList<>(11, list1);`
- the `ExampleNonEmptyList` class can get 2 parameters: the first parameter would be of some type and it would be the "head" of the list, and a second parameter which should be a list itself (`ExampleNonEmptyList` or `ExamplenEmptyList`)
- Ultimately, provide a factory feature for manufacturing families of related objects, to hide the actual implementation

My current implementation looks like this:

```
public abstract class ExampleAbstractList<T> {
    protected transient T head;
    protected transient T tail;
    ...
    public abstract void add(T e);
    ...

}

public final class ExampleNonEmptyList<T, U> extends ExampleAbstractList<T> {
    protected ArrayList<T> tail_elements = new ArrayList<>();
    public ExampleNonEmptyList(T head, U tail)
    {
        this.setHead(head);
        this.add((T) tail);
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void add(T e)
    {
        if(e instanceof ExampleNonEmptyList)
        {
            ExampleNonEmptyList enel = (ExampleNonEmptyList) e;
            T enHead = (T) enel.getHead();
            this.getTailElements().add(enHead);

            for(Object tElem : enel.getTailElements())
            {
                T tailElement = (T) tElem;

                this.getTailElements().add(tailElement);
            }
        } else if (e instanceof ExampleEmptyList) {
            ExampleEmptyList list = (ExampleEmptyList) e;
            if(list.size() == 0)
                return;

            for(Object el : list.getList())
            {
                this.getTailElements().add((T) el);
            }
        } else {
            this.getTailElements().add(e);
        }

        this.updateSize();
    }

    ...
}

public final class ExampleEmptyList<T> extends ExampleAbstractList<T> {

    private final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    public void add(T e)
    {
        this.getList().add(e);
        this.updateSize();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, the problem I have is that I cannot add an ExampleNonEmptyList to an ExampleEmptyList because I get the following error:

`incompatible types: ExampleAbstractList <Integer> cannot be converted to Integer` (when i am trying to add lists of integers)

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: ExampleAbstractList.add
    at Main.main(Main.java:42)
Java Result: 1
```

The code in Main.java:

```
32    ExampleAbstractList<Integer> list0   = new ExampleEmptyList<>(); 
33          list0.add(3);
34          ExampleAbstractList <Integer> list1   = new ExampleNonEmptyList<>(1, list0);
35          ExampleAbstractList <Integer> list2   = new ExampleNonEmptyList<>(32, list1);
36          list2.add(9);
...
Some prints
...          
42         list0.add(list1);
```

I understand the error and I am sure it is related with the type parameters, but I can't figure out how to fix this ... Could anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Comment: Why does `ExampleNonEmptyList` have two type parameters instead of one? You end up only casting `U tail` to type `T` anyway, and if they're going to be elements in the same underlying list they should be of the same type.

Comment: @Tenner when I did that I was doing it because the class has to receive two arguments of two different types, but now I see that I can reference the ExampleAbstractList there instead of 'U'. I fixed that now, but that doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your code that you are adding one list to another using `list0.add(list1)`. Try `list0.addAll(list1)` method instead. the addAll method takes `Collection<? extends E> c` as an argument and should be used in your particular case. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: i did this: 'public void addAll(Collection<? extends T> e)
    {
        this.getList().addAll(e);
        this.updateSize();
    }', but I get almost the same error, but it now became 'incompatible types: ExampleAbstractList <Integer> cannot be converted tCollection<? extends Integer>' instead of just Integer.

Comment: You just need to replace `list0.add(list1)` with `list0.addAll(list1)`. Is this what you have done?

Comment: yes, even casted list1 to Collection<?extends Integer>

Comment: Ok. but `list0.add(list1)` is definitely not correct. Will have to dig deeper.